# Not sure what's wrong with my form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Within a partial that is the layout for a collection of meal foods I have the following code:

```
  <tr class="food food-tr-<%= meal_food.id %>">
    <td><%= meal_food.name  %></td>
    <td>
      <% form_for :meal_food, meal_food, url: { controller: "foods", action: "update" }, html: { class: "meal_food_servings-#{meal_food.id}" } do |f| %>
        <%= f.number_field :servings %>
      <% end %>

    </td>
    <td><%= pluralize(meal_food.serving_size, meal_food.measure_type) %></td>
    <td><%= meal_food.fat    %></td>
    <td><%= meal_food.carbs  %></td>
    <td><%= meal_food.protien %> </td>
    <td><%= link_to "x", food_path(meal_food.id), method: :delete, remote: true %> </td>
  </tr>
```

In the second td cell I'm trying to render a small form that submits to the foods update action.

The error I keep running in to is this one upon simply trying to render the meals show page where these forms are.

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

I'm following the example from the rails guide here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

When I put

```
<%= meal_food %>
```

it outputs a meal_food object reference. So I'm not sure if that's the issue there.

Thanks!

---------- Routes.rb

```
      mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

      resources :status_updates do 
        collection do 
          delete :delete_all
        end
      end

      resources :meals  
      resources :foods do
        collection do
          get :search
        end
      end


      devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

      root to: 'static_pages#home'
      match '/faq', to: 'static_pages#faq'
      match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Comment: Show me your routes.rb file so I can have clear pictures of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for meal_food, url: food_url(meal_food.id) html: { class: "meal_food_servings-#{meal_food.id}" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Got this error undefined method `meal_food_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc1ec4627c8>:0x007fc1edcb3660>

Comment: I'm using food as a kind of parent prototype for meal_foods so right now there's no meal_foods controller. just a foods controller that handles all the food types. Might be a mistake :S

Comment: Show me your routes.rb file so I can have clear pictures of what you are doing.

Comment: Genius! Now I need to read in to food_url to learn what that is. Thanks!

Comment: @ninja08 read about routing in rails guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

This is url helper generated automatically when you called `resources :foods` in your routes.rb file.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking that out now